# checkbox label appearing with extra whitespace when loaded into a JQuery Dialog.

Tags: html, css, whitespace, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following Dialog http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/gULKy/1/ 
*If you look at the output in it's full window you can get a better idea of my issue.*

The checkbox and it's label are not appearing as expected. The html (outside of the dialog) displays the label tightly nuzzled next to the checkbox, however as you can see once it is displayed in the Dialog, you get the spacing.

If my fiddle does not show it. Here is a image of the results on my local server.

[image]

Comment: Ohh and before it is asked. this is appearing on **FF5** **Chrome** and **IE9** - however support for IE is not required.. so if the solution is not IE friendly that is ok.

Comment: AND yes I could just split the cell into two, but that doesn't answer why the rendering of the label/checkbox changes when i place it in the dialog.

Comment: Your input fields are 11.625em wide. Checkbox is also an input field.

Comment: ahahhhhhhh thankyou.. didn't catch that :)

Comment: @avetarman add it as your answer to get the check ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently a checkbox is a input ?? who knew ??

Read comments! Thanks all!